# Turnstile (\vdash) in adjoint functor and type theory.

Tags: category-theory, type-theory, adjoint-functors

Is common symbol $\vdash$ an abuse of notation or there is a deep sacred connection between 
$$\Gamma \vdash \lambda(a:A).a:\Pi(a:A).A$$
which is preorder and
$$G \vdash F \quad \mbox{($F$ is left adjoint to $G$)}$$
?

(the source of misunderstanding is [adjoined functor wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjoint_functors))

=========Edited=========

I found some useful [here](https://books.google.ru/books?id=0hhyL4WG3ngC&lpg=PA220&ots=lqsCUu1jqY&dq=turnstile%20and%20adjoint%20functor&pg=PA230#v=onepage&q=turnstile%20and%20adjoint%20functor&f=false) in Categorical Logic and Type Theory B.Jacobs (1999).

But I didn't understand about which categories author wrote.

Comment: Totally unrelated. And it's not an abuse of notation.

Answer (score 1):

The adjoint functor is not the normal turnstile, but the reverse turnstile 
⊣

There is quite a strong relation between the adjoint functor and semantics, see "The Galois connection between syntax and semantics"

http://www.logicmatters.net/resources/pdfs/Galois.pdf

but that would make one expect the double turnstile to be used...
It would be interesting to know if there is anything more to the use of this symbol.